# A testclass for @RestResource @HttpPost

Tags: apex, unit-test, httprequest, httppost, restresource

I have a @HttpPost method in @RestResource class:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/Something/*')
 global with sharing class HttpClass {


@HttpPost
global static String updateCustomObject() {
    //Fetching request

    RestRequest  req     = RestContext.request;   
    //Getting JSON String from request body
    String jsonInput  = req.requestBody.toString();
    JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(jsonInput);

    System.debug('Parser:' + jsonInput);

    jsonInput = jsonInput.replace(' ','');

    Object jsonUnpacked =  json.deserializeUntyped(jsonInput);
    System.debug(jsonUnpacked);

    User gUser = (User)JSON.deserialize(jsonInput, User.class);

    system.debug('user ' + gUser);


    X2017_questionnaire__c quest = new X2017_questionnaire__c(Name = gUser.name,Email_address__c = gUser.email,Pain_Factor_1__c = gUser.pain1,
                                                              Pain_Factor_2__c = gUser.pain2,Pain_Factor_3__c = gUser.pain3,
                                                              Pain_Factor_4__c = gUser.pain4,Pain_Factor_5__c = gUser.pain5,
                                                              Project_Objective_1__c = gUser.obj1,Project_Objective_2__c = gUser.obj2,
                                                              Project_Objective_3__c = gUser.obj3,Project_Objective_4__c = gUser.obj4,
                                                              Project_Objective_5__c = gUser.obj5);

    insert quest;

    /* //Below JSON Generator create response string
    JSONGenerator jsonGenerator = JSON.createGenerator(true);

    jsonGenerator.writeStartArray();
    jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
    //jsonGenerator.writeStringField('Email',emailFromJSONInput);
    jsonGenerator.writeStringField('Status', 'Success/Fail');
    jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
    jsonGenerator.writeEndArray();

    String responseJSONString = jsonGenerator.getAsString();*/

    List<X2017_questionnaire__c> lstOfQuest = [SELECT name,Email_address__c FROM X2017_questionnaire__c WHERE Email_address__c =:gUser.email];
    if (!lstOfQuest.isEmpty()){
        return 'Created Succesfully';
    }else {
        return 'Error';
    }

}

public class User {
    public String name;
    public String email;
    public String pain1;
    public String pain2;
    public String pain3;
    public String pain4;
    public String pain5;
    public String obj1;
    public String obj2;
    public String obj3;
    public String obj4;
    public String obj5;

}

}
```

How do I write a test class for the HTTPPost method? I tried using HttpMockCallout, but it works with HttpResponse and for my @HttpPost method I need a HttpRequest test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it in the following way, very similar to common apex class testing

```
@isTest
static void testHttpPost() {
    // prepare test-data

    //As Per Best Practice it is important to instantiate the Rest Context
    RestRequest req = new RestRequest();
    RestResponse res = new RestResponse();
    req.requestURI = '/services/apexrest/Something'; //Request URL
    req.httpMethod = 'POST';

    RestContext.request = req;
    RestContext.response= res;

    Test.startTest();
        String actual = null;//HttpClass.updateCustomObject();
    Test.stopTest();

    System.assertEquals('expected value', actual, 'Value is incorrect');
}
```

Comment: But do you actually send a request? I don't think you can Http h = Http(); h.send(req); I don't quite get that part

Comment: no, you cant do request in this way. But you can test functionality, as I answered

Comment: Sorry, I was getting the null error because I didn't set the JSON body. Thanks for the help. Spasibo!